# TSQL SELECT DISTINCT

Tags: mysql, sql, t-sql, group-by, distinct

I have looked at many examples but i cannot figure this out. Might be too simple for my tired brain. I have a table, I need to select all columns, with one distinct.

```
ID  CAT PRODUCT
=======================
1   21  Product1
2   21  Product2
3   23  Product2
4   24  Product3
5   24  Product5
6   25  Product4
7   25  Product6
```

I need to return

```
ID  CAT PRODUCT
=======================
1   21  Product1
3   23  Product2
4   24  Product3
7   25  Product6
```

ID and PRODUCT may or may not be the same. No condition needed. Category (CAT) needs to be distinct. THE Values returned need to be from same row.

In Mysql I can do the following, but MSSQL does not like it.

SELECT * FROM table GROUP BY CAT

Comment: Just to be clear do you care whether the values shown for `CAT` and `PRODUCT` are from the same row or not?

Comment: @MartinSmith - he does but only stated that in response to my answer

Comment: I edited in response to Hogan's answer. Yes, I do need them. Hogan provided a working query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the first row as ordered by id, distinct on cat you would use this

```
select id, cat, product from
(
   Select *,
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY cat ORDER BY ID) as num
   from table

) t
where num = 1
```

This creates a number of each element in the groups which would be created by a group by (as below) and then select the first one.

---

This would do it, I can't imagine why you would want this result.

```
select max(id) , cat, max(product)
from table
group by cat
```

or

```
select min(id) , cat, min(product)
from table
group by cat
```

would work.

You need to use an aggregate function, this function picks which item to use in the set of values found by the group by.

So for example when you group by cat you have two rows that need to be "combined".

```
1   21  Product1
2   21  Product2
```

for the id column and the product column you have to pick one of the two values to use if you use the aggregate function max() you will pick the max of those values.  In the same way min() will give you the min of those values.

Comment: what's the purpose of MAX that it will override GROUP BY issues?

Comment: @user1695981 - does that explain what min and max are doing?

Comment: I understand. This is not the desired result I would want then. I want the column values to be the values from ONE ROW. So if the group by selects say Nth Row, I want the cat and product to be from this row.

Comment: @user1695981 - ok, that was not in the question, which row?

Comment: @user1695981 - the first row as ordered by id?

Comment: Yes, I did a query and I was getting distinct CAT but the other rows were random (max). If there was to be added a ORDER BY clause, it would be ORDER BY ID ASC. So yes, first row to come upon

Comment: You my friend, need to give me your phone number! Joking. It's the result of a relief. That is the correct answer. So if I am understanding this correctly, We are getting the FIRST row which matches the distinct id, ordered by id

Comment: @user1695981 - yes that is exactly what it is doing.

Answer (score 2):

If ID is unique or primary key, then alternative solution would be:

```
SELECT tn.ID, tn.Cat, tn.Product  -- or just tn.* if all columns are to be selected
FROM
    (
        SELECT ID = MIN(ID)
        FROM TableName
        GROUP BY CAT
    ) x 
    INNER JOIN TableName tn ON
        x.ID = tn.ID
```

Nested 'x' query selects minimum ID for each unique category CAT and inner join returns rows from TableName with required ID's.

---

*Original answer.*

*Now it should be read as 'What you should not do if you want the column values to be from the same original row'. The example at the bottom was changed to show how data gets mixed.*

When Group By is used TSQL requires that all columns used should be either listed in GROUP 
BY clause or put inside aggregate functions (MIN, MAX, AVG, COUNT, etc.).

So, we need to choose which columns have to be distinct, and which columns should be put inside aggregate functions and what aggregate functions will be suitable for our purpose.

You need the `CAT` column to be distinct - you should GROUP BY it.

ID and PRODUCT columns are not constrained by any condition - so, we may aggregate them.
From all aggregate functions only MIN and MAX suit our purpose, because they do not change the type of the column they are applied to.

From your example the ID column always gets minimum value, so best option is to use MIN.

As for PRODUCT - you can use both MIN or MAX - I can see no difference in your current example.

```
SELECT MIN(Id), Cat, MAX(Product)
FROM TableName
GROUP BY Cat
```

How it works:

```
ID  CAT PRODUCT      ID  CAT PRODUCT
=================    ================
1   21  Product1     1   21              -- 1 is minimums for CAT 21
2   21  Product2            Product2     -- Product2 is maximum for CAT 21
-----------------    ----------------
3   23  Product2     3   23 Product2      -- Only one row for CAT 23
-----------------    ----------------
4   24  Product3     4   24               -- 4 is minimum for CAT 24
5   24  Product5            Product5      -- Product5 is maximum for CAT 24 
-----------------    ----------------
6   25  Product4     6   25               -- 6 is minimum for CAT 25
7   25  Product6            Product6      -- Product6 is maximum for CAT 25
```

So, the result would be:

```
ID  CAT PRODUCT
=================
1   21  Product2
3   23  Product2
4   24  Product5
6   25  Product6
```

As you can the CAT's are distinct, but column values are mixed between rows.

Comment: I don't think its a matter of which one I need to be better looking, I need the correct result for each row. If row 918 is to be THE GROUP by id, I need the cat and product for this row

Comment: @user1695981 Ah, now I see. Updated the answer.